# Map a saga with a list in the sagadata in nservicebus

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

I have a codebase where we need to send out a lot of messages and when they al complete we need to do some stuff.  We use nservicebus 7.X and I wanted to use a saga for this.
The problem is that the message i have to send out and get are not made by us so we cannot change those. The messages we send and get back have the same Id where I can find them by.

What i wanted to do keep a list of id's in the sagadata and use this list to map the return messages. I cannot find a way to map an id to a list in the sagadata.
I wanted to use iFindSagas but the example does not use a list. Is there maybe another way or can someone provide me with something that helps me on the right track.

The other hacky way i was thinking of is starting a second saga where i can directly map the ID's and then send a message back from this saga but it feels kinda hacky to do it like that and i would prefer to only use 1 saga for all of this.

Comment: can you provide a bit more details on the message structure?
What do you mean by: "The messages we send and get back have the same Id where I can find them by"? 
Do they all contain the same id?